# I m trying to use repeater inside repeater field any body can help me

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to use repeater inside repeater field. Could you please point me to where is the mistake?

```
<?php if(get_field('help_blocks')): ?>
    <?php while(has_sub_field('help_blocks')): ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="block">

                <h5><?php the_sub_field('block_title'); ?></h5>
                <?php the_sub_field('block_paragraph'); ?>

                <?php if(get_field('block_list')): ?>
                <ul class="list-style">
                    <?php while(has_sub_field('block_list')): ?>                    
                    <li><?php the_sub_field('list_item'); ?></li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>                  
                </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <img src="<?php the_sub_field('block_image'); ?>" alt="" />
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php the_sub_field('block_button_link'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('block_button'); ?></a>
                </div>      
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: what is your output ? does it show nothing? anything? a error? ...

Comment: Change `<?php if(get_field('block_list')): ?>` to `<?php if(get_sub_field('block_list')): ?>`. this should do the trick because you are already within a repeater...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're almost there.

You have this line:

```
<?php if(get_field('block_list')): ?>
```

It should be:

```
<?php if(get_sub_field('block_list')): ?>
```

Your nested repeater is a sub field of your repeater, so you need to use get_sub_field.